# Singularity Could not virtualize file system namespace: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, rstudio, singularity-container

I'm trying to run Singularity container inside Docker container from following `Dockerfile` (command to build: `docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t rocker-singularity .`):

```
FROM rocker/rstudio-stable:3.5.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    gcc \
    make \
    file \
    sudo \
    squashfs-tools \
    sshpass \
    libarchive-dev \
    vim

RUN VERSION=2.5.2 \
    && wget https://github.com/singularityware/singularity/releases/download/$VERSION/singularity-$VERSION.tar.gz \
    && tar xvf singularity-$VERSION.tar.gz \
    && cd singularity-$VERSION \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
    && make \
    && sudo make install \
    && cd - \
    && rm -rf singularity-${VERSION}*

RUN singularity pull --name ./hello-world.simg shub://vsoch/hello-world
```

using command:

```
docker run -it rocker-singularity:latest sudo singularity shell hello-world.simg
```

but I get error:

```
$ docker run -it rocker-singularity:latest sudo singularity --debug shell hello-world.simg
Enabling debugging
Ending argument loop
Singularity version: 2.5.2-dist
Exec'ing: /usr/local/libexec/singularity/cli/shell.exec
Evaluating args: 'hello-world.simg'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          message_init()                            Set messagelevel to: 5
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Initialize configuration file: /usr/local/etc/singularity/singularity.conf
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Starting parse of configuration file /usr/local/etc/singularity/singularity.conf
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key allow setuid = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key max loop devices = '256'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key allow pid ns = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key config passwd = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key config group = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key config resolv_conf = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount proc = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount sys = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount dev = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount devpts = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount home = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount tmp = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount hostfs = 'no'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key bind path = '/etc/localtime'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key bind path = '/etc/hosts'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key user bind control = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key enable overlay = 'try'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key mount slave = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key sessiondir max size = '16'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key allow container squashfs = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key allow container extfs = 'yes'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Got config key allow container dir = 'yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_parse()                Finished parsing configuration file '/usr/local/etc/singularity/singularity.conf'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_init()               Initializing Singularity Registry
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'COMMAND' = 'shell'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(COMMAND, shell) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'SYSCONFDIR' = '/usr/local/etc'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(sysconfdir, /usr/local/etc) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'VERSION' = '2.5.2-dist'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(version, 2.5.2-dist) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'IMAGE' = 'hello-world.simg'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(IMAGE, hello-world.simg) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'MESSAGELEVEL' = '5'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(MESSAGELEVEL, 5) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'BINDIR' = '/usr/local/bin'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(bindir, /usr/local/bin) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'LOCALSTATEDIR' = '/usr/local/var'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(localstatedir, /usr/local/var) = 0
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'LIBEXECDIR' = '/usr/local/libexec'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(libexecdir, /usr/local/libexec) = 0
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'HOME'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'TARGET_UID'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'TARGET_GID'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_init()                   Initializing user info
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_init()                   Set the calling user's username to: root
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_init()                   Marking uinfo structure as ready
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_init()                   Obtaining home directory
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_init()                   Set home (via getpwuid()) to: /root
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_suid_init()                   Running SUID program workflow
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_suid_init()                   Checking program has appropriate permissions
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_suid_init()                   Checking configuration file is properly owned by root
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_suid_init()                   Checking if singularity.conf allows us to run as suid
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Called singularity_config_get_bool(allow setuid, yes)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_impl()       Returning configuration value allow setuid='yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Return singularity_config_get_bool(allow setuid, yes) = 1
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'NOSUID'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_userns()                 Invoking the user namespace
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Called singularity_config_get_bool(allow user ns, yes)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_impl()       No configuration entry found for 'allow user ns'; returning default value 'yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Return singularity_config_get_bool(allow user ns, yes) = 1
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_userns()                 Not virtualizing USER namespace: running as root
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_userns()                 Returning singularity_priv_init(void)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_drop()                   Running as root, not changing privileges
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_multi_impl() No configuration entry found for 'autofs bug path'; returning default value ''
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_autofs()              No autofs bug path in configuration, skipping
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'DAEMON_START'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'DAEMON_JOIN'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_daemon_init()                 Not joining a daemon, daemon join not set
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'WRITABLE'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          main()                                    Instantiating read only container image object
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning value from registry: 'IMAGE' = 'hello-world.simg'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_init()                  Calling image_init for each file system module
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_dir_init()              Opening file descriptor to directory: /hello-world.simg
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_dir_init()              This is not a directory based image
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_squashfs_init()         Checking if writable image requested
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_squashfs_init()         Opening file descriptor to image: /hello-world.simg
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_squashfs_init()         Checking that file pointer is a Singularity image
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_squashfs_init()         Checking for magic in the top of the file
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_squashfs_init()         File is a valid SquashFS image
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_image_init()                  got image_init type for squashfs
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Called singularity_config_get_bool(allow container squashfs, yes)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_impl()       Returning configuration value allow container squashfs='yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Return singularity_config_get_bool(allow container squashfs, yes) = 1
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'DAEMON_JOIN'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'CLEANUPDIR'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Adding value to registry: 'CLEANUPD_FD' = '-1'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_set()                Returning singularity_registry_set(CLEANUPD_FD, -1) = 0
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'DAEMON_JOIN'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'NOSESSIONCLEANUP'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'NOCLEANUP'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_cleanupd()                    Not running a cleanup thread, no 'SINGULARITY_CLEANUPDIR' defined
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'DAEMON_JOIN'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns()                  Calling: _singularity_runtime_ns_ipc()
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Called singularity_config_get_bool(allow ipc ns, yes)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_impl()       No configuration entry found for 'allow ipc ns'; returning default value 'yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Return singularity_config_get_bool(allow ipc ns, yes) = 1
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'UNSHARE_IPC'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns_ipc()              Not virtualizing IPC namespace on user request
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns()                  Calling: _singularity_runtime_ns_pid()
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Called singularity_config_get_bool(allow pid ns, yes)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_impl()       Returning configuration value allow pid ns='yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Return singularity_config_get_bool(allow pid ns, yes) = 1
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'UNSHARE_PID'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns_pid()              Not virtualizing PID namespace on user request
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns()                  Calling: _singularity_runtime_ns_net()
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_registry_get()                Returning NULL on 'UNSHARE_NET'
VERBOSE [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns_net()              Not virtualizing network namespace on user request
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns()                  Calling: _singularity_runtime_ns_mnt()
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Called singularity_config_get_bool(mount slave, yes)
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_value_impl()       Returning configuration value mount slave='yes'
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_config_get_bool_char_impl()   Return singularity_config_get_bool(mount slave, yes) = 1
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_priv_escalate()               Running as root, not changing privileges
DEBUG   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns_mnt()              Virtualizing FS namespace
Singularity: action-suid (U=0,P=1)> Could not virtualize file system namespace: Operation not permitted

ERROR   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns_mnt()              Could not virtualize file system namespace: Operation not permitted
Singularity: action-suid (U=0,P=1)> Retval = 255

ABORT   [U=0,P=1]          singularity_runtime_ns_mnt()              Retval = 255
```

I googled a lot and found [this issue](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/632), but proposed solution didn't work. Can you help please?

Comment: Don't know that it will help with the permissions to build inside a docker build, but the v2 versions of singularity before 2.6.1 have security issues and 2.6.1 is no longer receiving any updates. I recommend using v3+ if at all possible.

Comment: It's not possible. I have to use 2.5.2 to reproduce remote server's environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building the docker image based on the Dockerfile you gave I was able to run the singularity image via the linked solution. Docker Engine v19.03.4.

```
$ docker run --privileged -it rocker-singularity:latest sudo singularity shell hello-world.simg
Singularity: action-suid (U=0,P=6)> USER=root, IMAGE='hello-world.simg', COMMAND='shell'

Singularity: Invoking an interactive shell within container...

bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
Singularity hello-world.simg:/>
```

and

```
$ docker run --privileged -it rocker-singularity:latest sudo singularity run hello-world.simg
Singularity: action-suid (U=0,P=6)> USER=root, IMAGE='hello-world.simg', COMMAND='run'

/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.UTF-8)
RaawwWWWWWRRRR!! Avocado!
```